# Landau free energy, ising mean field and the "full partition function". Discrepancy between two similar approaches

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, partition-function, mean-field-theory

From what I understand, for example, in the neighbor interactions Ising model, we can write the partition function as:

$$Z = \sum_{m}\Omega(m)e^{-\beta E(m)}=\sum_{m}e^{-\beta \tilde F(m)}=e^{-\beta F}\tag 1$$

where $\Omega(m)$ is the number of configurations corresponding to a magnetization $m$, $\tilde F(m)$ is a "partial" free energy corresponding to $m$. It's what is approximated using the landau free energy and $F$ is the free energy of the system.

Now, the mean field of the ising model is:

$$H_{MF}=\frac{NqJm^2}{2}-qJm\sum_{i=1}^Ns_i \tag 2$$

And summing over all configurations we get:

$$Z_{MF}=\prod_{i=1}^N\sum_{s_i=\pm 1}e^{-\beta H_{MF}}=e^{-\frac{\beta NqJm^2}{2}}[2\cosh(\beta qJm)]^N \tag 3$$

$F(m) = -T\log(Z_{MF}(m))$ definitevely gives a variational free energy (the equivalent of $\tilde F$ in equation (1) and **not** F). Using this, we can find the self-consistency equation, for example by minimizing $F(m)$ with respect to $m$.

I've also seen an other way to do this mean field, with this hamiltonian (for example in the statistical field theory lecture of David Tong: [1.1.2 Mean Field Theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/sft.html) ).

$$H'_{MF}=\frac{NqJm^2}{2}-qJNm^2= -NqJm^2/2\tag 4$$

where it looks like $m$ is taken to be equal to $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i}s_i$ which seems a bit odd since I believe that $m$ is supposed to be a thermal average not an average over "sites". Anyway we can write the partition function as the sum over all the configurations (as before) which is now a sum over possible magnetizations:

$$Z'_{MF} = \sum_{m}\Omega(m)e^{\beta NqJm^2/2}\tag 5$$

Again, following David Tong, we can find $\Omega(m)$ and so we find that:

$$Z'_{MF}=\sum_{m}\exp(-\beta (-NqJm^2/2 - T(\log(2)-(m+1)\log(m+1)/2-(1-m)\log(1-m)/2)))=\sum_{m}e^{-\beta \tilde F(m)}\tag 6$$

In this case $-T\log(Z'_{MF})$ **doesn't give** a variational free energy (it's the "full free energy"), the variational free energy is (as expected from (1)) the big expression in the exponential. And with $\tilde F(m)$ we can find the same self-consistency equation as before.

---

I'm confused, these two approaches seem to me to be the same, and yet: $-T\log(Z_{MF})$ is a **variational** free energy and $-T\log(Z'_{MF})$ isn't (it's the "full free energy"). In the first case, the variational free energy is $F(m)=-T\log(Z_{MF})$ while in the second case, the variational free energy is  $\tilde F(m)\neq-T\log(Z'_{MF})$.

When I first saw the mean field approach, I convinced myself that the partition function given by $H_{MF}$ would then give a **variational** free energy. This is the case for $Z_{MF}$ but not for $Z'_{MF}$.

So, is a mean field approach supposed to give us a partition function dependent upon an order parameter, here $Z_{MF}(m)$? Or is it supposed to gives us a full partition function, here $Z'_{MF}$? Why these two similar/mean field approaches give differents objects at the end?

I've always wonder why we do we consider that $m$ was constant when we evaluate the partition function (3) even though we are summing over all value of $s_i$ (and $m$ and $s_i$ are linked, in all case, I suppose the self-consistency equation takes care of that part?). Is this the reason why the first approach yields a partition function dependent upon $m$, because we are working with only one value of $m$ when we do the sum (but it seems kind of weird, as long as we sum over all possible states, it should be equivalent to a sum over all possible magnetizations)?

Comment: It looks like you are talking about the *infinite range Ising model* - it is worth specifying, since there are also other Ising models (and mean field does not give correct answer for many of them)

Comment: I think, I'm only dealing with neighbor interactions here! What makes you think the interactions are infinite?

Comment: firstly, you didn't write the model, so it is hard to judge what you are dealing with. But normally one does not use mean field theory in 1D and 2D, since it fails. However, for an *infinite-range Ising model*, where every spin is coupled to every spin, it is exact and often used as an example, e.g., in Negele& Orland

Answer (score 2):

> [...] it looks like m is taken to be equal to $\frac{1}{N}\sum_i s_i$ which seems a bit odd since I believe that m is supposed to be a thermal average not an average over "sites".

Yes, that's right.  The $m$ which appears at that section of Tong's notes is not the thermal average magnetization, but rather the average magnetization of a particular configuration of spins.

For clarity, let's use the symbol $m$ to mean the thermal average magnetization and $\hat m = \frac{1}{N}\sum_i s_i$ to mean the average magnetization of a particular configuration $\{s_i\}$.  From the definition of the free energy, we have that $Z = e^{-\beta F}$.  However, in the mean field approach we can write

$$Z = \sum_{\{s_i\}}e^{-\beta E(\{s_i\})}\rightarrow \sum_{\hat m}\Omega(\hat m) e^{-\beta E(\hat m)} = \sum_\hat m e^{-\beta \hat F(\hat m)} $$

where we define $\hat F(\hat m):= E(\hat m) - \frac{1}{\beta}\log\big(\Omega(\hat m)\big)$.

In the thermodynamic limit, $e^{-\beta \hat F(\hat m)}$ is an extremely sharply-peaked function about its maximum $e^{-\beta \hat F_0} \equiv e^{-\beta\hat F(\hat m_0)}$, where $\hat m_0$ minimizes $\hat F$.  As a result, we can say that

$$e^{-\beta F} = \sum_{\hat m} e^{-\beta \hat F(\hat m)} \approx e^{-\beta F_0}$$
and that $m \approx \hat m_0$.  It is in this sense that the two approaches you refer to produce the same result in the limit of large $N$.

Comment: Ok It's clearer, but then I have an other issue. In the usual mean field theory where we use the thermal average. We get: $F(m) = -T\log(Z_{MF}(m))$. In this case, does it make sense to say that, really, the total partition function is $Z = \sum_{m}e^{-\beta F(m)}$ where we sum over all **thermal average** and this is why we minimize $F(m)$ (for the same reason you explained)?

Comment: In fact, I guess I don't understand why we minimize the free energy obtained by the thermal average but I think I understand why it's minimized in the case you explained.